# Python Generate password with options

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I've got a PyQt5 gui set up for password generation.

[image: Gui Here]

It has multiple options for modifying the password, But the best i could come up with so far to generate the password with the modifiers applied is below

```
def generate_click(self,value):
    password_length     = self.horizontalSlider.value() # Comes Back as a int
    password_uppercase  = self.checkBox.isChecked()     # Comes Back True/False
    password_lowercase  = self.checkBox_2.isChecked()   # Comes Back True/False
    password_numbers    = self.checkBox_3.isChecked()   # Comes Back True/False
    password_special    = self.checkBox_4.isChecked()   # Comes Back True/False

    print(password_length, password_uppercase, password_lowercase, password_numbers, password_special)



    if (password_uppercase == True and password_lowercase == True and password_numbers == True and password_special == True):

        alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"

    if (password_uppercase == True and password_lowercase == True and password_numbers == True and password_special == True):


    if (password_uppercase == True and password_lowercase == True and password_numbers == True and password_special == True):


    if (password_uppercase == True and password_lowercase == True and password_numbers == True and password_special == True):
```

**Is there a better way of doing this?** Thanks

Comment: What does it mean *Is there a better way of doing this?* ? If it does not say which parameter is better this question tends to be based on opinions making it off-topic

Comment: For one, `password_uppercase == True` and the like can just be replaced with `password_uppercase`. It'll give the same result.

Comment: Change `if (password_uppercase == True and password_lowercase == True and password_numbers == True and password_special == True):` to `if password_uppercase and password_lowercase and password_numbers and password_special:`, it's redundant

Comment: Start with an empty list, then for each of your boolean flags, extend that list with the relevant characters if it's wanted... Then sample from the end list...

Comment: This question doesn't really seem to have a specific programming problem here (save for code improvements). So, I think this question could be a better fit over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I agree with @SeanFrancisN.Ballais but when I tried to vote to close and migrate it, Code Review was not among the options given. Not sure how to proceed so I'm skipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'd do this would look something like this:

```
alphabet = ''
if password_uppercase:
    alphabet += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
if password_lowercase:
    alphabet += "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
if password_numbers:
    alphabet += "0123456789"
if password_special:
    alphabet += "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"

# if None was selected, add a default
alphabet = alphabet or "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Also notice that as `password_uppercase`, `password_lowercase`, etc. variables are Boolean, making a comparison of their value is pretty redundant. I'd suggest you using, i.e., `password_uppercase` instead of `password_uppercase == True` and `not password_uppercase` instead of `password_uppercase == False`

Answer (score 0):

As @Jon Clements suggested you might want to do something like:

```
import string
import random

def generate_click(self,value):
    password_length     = self.horizontalSlider.value() # Comes Back as a int
    password_uppercase  = self.checkBox.isChecked()     # Comes Back True/False
    password_lowercase  = self.checkBox_2.isChecked()   # Comes Back True/False
    password_numbers    = self.checkBox_3.isChecked()   # Comes Back True/False
    password_special    = self.checkBox_4.isChecked()   # Comes Back True/False

    print(password_length, password_uppercase, password_lowercase, password_numbers, password_special)

    # Initialize the set of character to choose from
    l = []

    # Check your different flags and extend the list accordingly
    if password_uppercase:
        l.extend(string.ascii_uppercase)
    if password_lowercase:
        l.extend(string.ascii_lowercase)
    if password_numbers:
        l.extend(string.digits)
    if password_special:
        l.extend(string.punctuation)

    # Build your password
    try:
        password = "".join(random.choices(l, k=password_length))
    except IndexError:  # Necessary if no default set of characters
        password = ""

    # Display your password
```

Using the string module (always available in python), means you do not have to type in the set of available characters.
Hope this helps in your endeavor.